# Angled slice of 3D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

In NumPy I understand how to slice 2D arrays from a 3D array using [this article](http://www.pythoninformer.com/python-libraries/numpy/index-and-slice/):

```
array = [[[0  1  2]
          [3  4  5]
          [6  7  8]]

         [[9  10 11]
          [12 13 14]
          [15 16 17]]

         [[18 19 20]
          [21 22 23]
          [24 25 26]]]
```

Slicing would give me:

```
i_slice = array[0]

    [[0  1  2]
     [3  4  5]
     [6  7  8]]

j_slice = array[:, 0]

    [[0  1  2]
     [9  10 11]
     [18 19 20]]

k_slice = array[:, :, 0]

    [[0  3  6]
     [9  12 15]
     [18 21 24]]
```

But is it possible to slice at a 45 degree angle? Such as:

```
j_slice_down = array[slice going down starting from index 0]

    [[0  1  2]
     [12 13 14]
     [24 25 26]]
```

I can do this on all 3 axis' going up or down and wrapping around with lists and for loops, but there must be a better way in NumPy.

Comment: `a[np.eye(len(a),dtype=bool)]` with `a` as the input array?

Comment: Another with `einsum`, should be more efficient : `np.einsum('iij->ij',a)`.

Comment: @EngerBewza Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [145]: arr[np.arange(3), np.arange(3),:]
Out[145]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: for small slice ranges, I like this the arrange, since you can arrange the slicing to suit if expanded  … eg. a[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],:] or … a[[2,1,0],[0,1,2],:]

Comment: @hpaulj - This seems to be what I'm looking for. So for I can apply this to all axis's by placing np.arange in other placements than your example. Also, reversing the output of np.arange allows me to select in the other direction and starting in the negatives allows me to creating wrapping selections.

Comment: `np.where(np.eye(3))` produces these same two ranges, so my answer is related to @Divakar's `eye` comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `np.diagonal`:

```
arr = np.array([[[0  ,1  ,2],
          [3  ,4  ,5],
          [6  ,7  ,8]],
         [[9  ,10 ,11],
          [12 ,13 ,14],
          [15 ,16 ,17]],
         [[18 ,19 ,20],
          [21 ,22 ,23],
          [24 ,25 ,26]]])

np.diagonal(arr).T
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [24, 25, 26]])
```

Comment: np.diagonal has axis1 and axis2 as kwargs.  They let you choose which diagonal slice of arr is returned.